# Custom MVC HTML extension for DateTime property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

Is it possible to create a custom html helper for asp.net mvc that would take a DateTime as TProperty, create 3 textboxes for day, month and year and allow me to get the full DateTime back when posting the form ?

In other words, I want something that is written like this in Razor :

```
@Html.TripleTextboxFor(userModel => userModel.Birthdate)
```

That outputs something like :

```html
<input type="text" name="BirthdateDay" />
<input type="text" name="BirthdateMonth" />
<input type="text" name="BirthdateYear" />
```

And finally, is it possible to create such an extension without doing extra model custom binding to retrieve the DateTime posted ?

Here is what I have been using so far. It is ok to display the value, but I have extra work to get the DateTime back + validation.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TripleBirthDateTextBoxes<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    DateTime dt = (DateTime)metaData.Model;

    output.Append(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(m => dt.Day));
    output.Append(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(m => dt.Month));
    output.Append(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(m => dt.Year));

    return new MvcHtmlString(output.ToString());
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Not impossible but quite complicated. Check [Scott's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx)

Comment: @tweray is right. Model binders are the way to go in order to split up your `DateTime`. The only drawback I see is that the `HtmlHelper` is not self contained, i.e. you don't have all the code needed to make it work inside the same method.